# mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' on Scrapinghub

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, scrapinghub

I try to run my spider on scrapinghub, and run it getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 80, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 105, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings
    mw = create_instance(mwcls, settings, crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 144, in create_instance
    return objcls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/__main__.egg/skripsi/pipelines.py", line 19, in __init__
  File "/app/__main__.egg/skripsi/pipelines.py", line 29, in create_connection
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 173, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 780, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 284, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 532, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111 Connection refused)
```

I have tried to add mysql-connector-python on requirements.txt and Configure my dependencies on scrapinghub.yml like this [this](https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200400-deploying-python-dependencies-for-your-projects-in-scrapy-cloud)

my requirements.txt

```
mysql-connector-python
```

my scrapinghub.yml

```
projects:
  default: 396892
stacks:
  default: scrapy:1.6-py3
requirements:
  file: requirements.txt
```

My pipelines.py

```
import mysql.connector

class SkripsiPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        # dispatcher.connect(self.close_spider, signals.close_spider)
        # self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = '127.0.0.1',
            password = '',
            user = 'root',
            database = 'news'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return item

    def store_db(self,item):
        self.curr.execute("INSERT INTO news_tb (url, title, author, time, crawl_time, imagelink, content) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(
            item['url'][0],
            item['title'][0],
            item['author'][0],
            item['time'][0],
            item['crawl_time'][0],
            item['imagelink'][0],
            item['content'][0]
        ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

This is the mistake I faced when running a spider on scrapinghub. Anyone who is familiar with this problem, please let me know.

thanks.

Comment: Can you check whether mysql service is running?

Comment: I am also confused, there is no MySql in my services

Comment: Are you using windows or linux environment?

Comment: using Windows and I have created Mysql in my services as in this tutorial https://www.dbrnd.com/2018/03/mysql-missing-mysql-service-in-services-msc-windows-system/
what's the next step

Comment: Use this blog to determine the mysql server is there https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/10/how-to-start-stop-restart-mysql-server.html

Comment: the statement mysql is running, and tried to run the spider in scrapinghub but the error still appears

Comment: Can you connect your local db with a query tool? Like mysql work bench or heidiSQL?

Comment: I've done it, but it's still the same problem

Comment: did your server is open for all types of requests? did ping work? Also, try to connect it directly via the terminal? Check this out-> https://www.tecmint.com/fix-error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111/

Comment: can you show the configuration that you've done in the query tool to get connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible at all. Because of ScrapyCloud doesn't provide any SQL support. You are trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 - it's localhost, it means that MySQL should be installed on ScrapyCloud and running. That's impossible.
One thing that I would recommend you is to run MySQL somewhere on the web and connect to in by domain/global ip address